# best practice for debian distribution upgrade - what happens with the rest of the LAMP?

Tags: debian, lamp, upgrade

I am planning of upgrading the LAMP stack that I have.

```
Debian Lenny 5.09 - current version is 6.0
Apache 2.2.9 - current 2.2.21
MySQL 5.0.51a - current 5.5.20
PHP 5.2.6 - current PHP 5.3.9
```

I am curious if I should start with the debian upgrade and the rest will follow from the new repositories, or I should start with PHP/Mysql first and leave the distro update at the end.

What is the best practice?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your LAMP stack is installed through Debian's package management system, it'd get updated automatically during system upgrade. You can find the official documentation about upgrade from Lenny to Squeeze right [here](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/release-notes/ch-upgrading.html).

Upgrades between major versions may sometimes go wrong if not performed carefully, so I would suggest to read the above mentioned page in order to prepare yourself for the process and avoid undesired situations.